# How to get json data from url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, geoserver

I have url with json data.
Ex: `{"type" : "feature", "name": name"...}`

URL is GeoServer URL.

I want to get JSON data.

what should I do?

```
1) $.ajax(url,
       { dataType: "jsonp" }
   ).done(function ( data ) {
       console.log('done will never be called, unfortunately...');
   });

2) $.ajax({
   jsonp:false,
   jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
   type: 'GET',
   url: url,
   async:false,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data){
       alert('success');
   }
  });

3) var view = map.getView();
          var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
          var source = untiled.get('visible') ? untiled.getSource() : tiled.getSource();
          var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
      {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});

       if (url) {

              $.ajax({
               jsonp:false,
               jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
               type: 'GET',
               url: url,
               async:false,
               dataType: 'jsonp',
               success: function(data){
                   alert('success');
               }
           });
       }
```

but this is not working.
I don't get json data.

Comment: Look in the console.. Likely a CORS issue

Comment: Try adding `error` to your ajax. So, that you will be able to see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Ajax cal with the options which has consoled the suucess and errors.. and easy to find if any error.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      crossDomain: true,
      data:'',
      success: function (response) {
        var res = JSON.parse(response);
        // Console response data
        console.log(res);
        // Do your Operations here...
      },

      error: function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I got XMLHttpRequest: network error 0x80070005, Access is denied.